# How do I debug my .net CF app on my physical device?

Tags: debugging, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I am pretty new to WinMo development. I managed to write my first app, debug it via the emulators but I failed to run the debug session on my physical phone.
I connected my phone to the development PC via ActiveSync, but that alone did not make my phone show up on the list among the selectable emulators. Is there anything I need to do before this would work?

Alternative: I want to program with the G-sensor and the bluetooth capabilites of the phone. Is there a way to play with them via emulators? How on earth do you shake an emulator? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you hooked up and confirmed that ActiveSync is working, you should be able to select the "Mobile Device" form the target list. It is not listed by name, it simply is the only entry not ending in emulator.